# Projection matrix when $M^TM$ is singular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Compute the projection matrix of $M=\begin{pmatrix}2&0&2\\ 1&1&2\\ 1&1&2\\ 2&0&2\end{pmatrix}.$

The projection matrix is given by $P=M(M^TM)^{-1}M^T$, but in this case $M^TM = \begin{pmatrix}10&2&12\\ 2&2&4\\ 12&4&16\end{pmatrix}$ that isn't singular e.g $\det(M^TM)=0$ so there isn't an inverse for this. How can I compute the projection matrix for this kind of situation?

Comment: You can use the [pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) and the resulting matrix is still an orthogonal projector.

Comment: Either use the pseudo-inverse as Rammus suggested, this always works. Alternatively, you realize that the third column of $M$ is the sum of the first and the second and hence it is in the column space spanned by the first two. So for the projector on the column space of $M$ you can simply consider only the first two columns and then run your formula...

Comment: Start with the definition of what want to achieve, namely, define "the projection matrix of a matrix".